# How do I add child node to soap envelope in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

To use a web service I need to insert a child node in soapEnvelope, as a first child to the Body node. In this node I then want to import an Xml document.
However, it fails, keeps making it as a sibling node in parallel to my import, whatever I do. What am I doing wrong? Here my code (importeddoc is an incoming xml document)

```
    XmlDocument soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelope.LoadXml("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv = 
    \"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
    xmlns:xd=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"> 
    </soapenv:Envelope>");
    XmlNode headernode = soapEnvelope.CreateNode("element", 
   "soapenv:Header", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    XmlNode bodynode = soapEnvelope.CreateNode("element", 
   "soapenv:Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    XmlElement root = soapEnvelope.DocumentElement;
    root.AppendChild(headernode);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new 
    XmlNamespaceManager(importeddoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("myextranodens", "http://....");
    
    XmlNode containernode = 
    importeddoc.SelectSingleNode("/myimportdata", nsmgr);
    XmlNode importNode = soapEnvelope.ImportNode(containernode, 
    true);
    XmlNode myextranode = 
   bodynode.AppendChild(soapEnvelope.CreateElement("myextranodename"));
    
    XmlNode final = myextranode.AppendChild(importNode);
    bodynode.AppendChild(final);
    root.AppendChild(bodynode);
    return soapEnvelope;
```

I want it so:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <myextranodename>
     <myimportdata>
    </myextranodename>
</soapenv:Body>
```

.. but now goes:

```
<myextranodename></myextranodename>
<myimportdata>
```

What am I doing wrong? Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I have to remove the last bodynode append child:

```
bodynode.AppendChild(final);
```